# Debbuging models.py code

Tags: python, django

What is the way to debug Python code inside models.py code. For other files I would use, for example:

```
assert 1==0, 'Some data'
```

This would work for example at views.py, but not at models.py. What method do you use to debug models.py?

Looking for some way to trace the info (e.g. trace(), console.debug() or smth similar).

Comment: Have you tried to unit test your model ?

Comment: No, I haven't. I am new to Django and Python. Is unit test a legit way to debug your models.py? Isn't there any simple way like trace() or console.debug() in other languages?

Comment: By they way, in the end I used unit test along with pdb.set_trace to debug models.py effectively. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Models code is not different from any other code. If you are calling a model method from a view or the console, it gets executed in exactly the same way. So, just like any other code, you can use the built-in Python debugger to step through your code:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

And, contrary to your statement, assertions do work just as well in models as in views.

Comment: Thank you for help, Daniel. This is the way I am going to use now for debugging purposes.